# Convert Data Type Inside Array on Angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, multidimensional-array

I have a dynamically generated Array that shown from console.log(val) just like this :

```
[{Chrome:"61.41"},{Internet Explorer:"11.84"},{Firefox:"10.85"}]
```

My Code (on Angular component.ts) :

```
this.customerservice.getTotalCustomer().subscribe((res)=>{
   this.apiData = res;
   let result = [];
    this.apiData.forEach(item => {
      let prop = Object.keys(item)[0];
      result.push({name: prop, y: item[prop]});
    })
    console.log(result);  
})
```

My question is, Is it possible to convert or change my array format just be like this ?

```
[{ name: 'Chrome', y: 61.41 }, { name: 'Internet Explorer', y: 11.84 }, { name: 'Firefox', y: 10.85 }]
```

Thanks guys...

Answer (score 2):

```
let newData = this.apiData.map(item => ({ name: Object.keys(item)[0], y: item[Object.keys(item)[0]] }))
```

Comment: it just shown "[{name: "Chrome", y: "61.41"}]" @Fateme Fazli, not whole data.

Comment: hi @Fateme Fazli, does it relate with my data type : [{Chrome:"61.41"},{Internet Explorer:"11.84"},{Firefox:"10.85"}] ? not [{"Chrome":"61.41"},{Internet "Explorer":"11.84"},{"Firefox":"10.85"}]

Answer (score 1):

You could use array.reduce and transform the object as follows,

DEMO

```js
var arrOfObj = [{"Chrome":"61.41"},{"Internet Explorer":"11.84"},{"Firefox":"10.85"}];

var result = arrOfObj.reduce(function(items, item) {
  var fixed = {};
  var keys = Object.keys(item);
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    fixed.name = key;
    fixed.y = item[key];
  });
  items.push(fixed);
  return items;
}, []);


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
let arr= [{"Chrome":"61.41"},{"Internet Explorer":"11.84"},{"Firefox":"10.85"}];

let result = [];
arr.forEach(item => {
  let prop = Object.keys(item)[0];
  result.push({name: prop, y: item[prop]});
})

console.log(result);
```

Also check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/map-js-objects-amit?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for full working code

Comment: it just shown "[{name: "Chrome", y: "61.41"}]" man, not whole data.

Comment: Did you take some time to run the code snippet added?

Comment: on your code snippet is right, nothing wrong with it. but i dont know if im trying to implement your solution to my code is just give ouput as like i mention above

Comment: Can you please show your implementation? Add that in your question.

Comment: i've been added to my question sir @Amin Chigadani

Comment: See this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/map-js-objects-amit?file=src/app/app.component.ts Its exactly what you need.

Comment: Hi sir @Amit Chigadani, is it any something that relate with my data type : [{Chrome:"61.41"},{Internet Explorer:"11.84"},{Firefox:"10.85"}] ? and not [{"Chrome":"61.41"},{"Internet Explorer":"11.84"},{"Firefox":"10.85"}] ?

Comment: Internet explorer is a wrong key here, it has to be enclosed within single quotes, because object attribute names cannot contain space in them.

Comment: so, what should i do sir ? @Amit Chigadani

Comment: You should change the way your response is being returned. Because that is not a valid json. Add single quotes to all those object attributes

Answer (score 0):

**[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** is another way of mapping the object array into a new array of objects my using the second mapping argument.

```js
const array = [{"Chrome":"61.41"},{"Internet Explorer":"11.84"},{"Firefox":"10.85"}];
const arrayConv = Array.from(array, obj => { return {"name":Object.keys(obj)[0], "y":Object.values(obj)[0] } });
console.log(arrayConv);
```